# VHDL: analogous to Verlilog syntax for describing an adder

Tags: syntax, vhdl, verilog

I'm trying to replicate this shortcut for easily generating an adder while separating the output carry and the result:

```
reg [31:0] op_1;
reg [31:0] op_2;
reg [31:0] sum;
reg carry_out;

always @(posedge clk)
    { carry_out, sum } <= op_1 + op_2;
```

In my case, it's Ok to use the nonstandard `ieee.STD_LOGIC_UNSIGNED`.

I would prefer not to use VHDL-2008 features as I am stuck with Xilinx ISE, at the moment.

Comment: No attempt and no research. There are many examples on stack overflow. And the rest of the internet.

Comment: @JHBonarius My internet search skills only found unnecessarily complicated manipulations involving temporary signals/variables, but no quick way to describe it as in my Verilog example. As it can be deduced from the answers, there is no such a way without VHDL-2008. So, I think my question should be valid.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Too bad that VHDL 2008 is not an option. If it was, the following would make it:

```
library ieee;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;
use ieee.numeric_std.all;

entity foo is
  port(
    clk:  in  std_ulogic;
    a, b: in  u_unsigned(31 downto 0); 
    s:    out u_unsigned(31 downto 0); 
    co:   out std_ulogic
  );  
end entity foo;

architecture rtl of foo is
begin

  process(clk)
  begin
    if rising_edge(clk) then
      (co, s) <= ('0' & a) + ('0' & b); 
    end if;
  end process;

end architecture rtl;
```

But as you are stuck with older versions, the following should work:

```
library ieee;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;
use ieee.numeric_std.all;

entity foo is
  port(
    clk:  in  std_ulogic;
    a, b: in  unsigned(31 downto 0);
    s:    out unsigned(31 downto 0);
    co:   out std_ulogic
  );
end entity foo;

architecture rtl of foo is
begin

  process(clk)
    variable tmp: unsigned(32 downto 0);
  begin
    if rising_edge(clk) then
      tmp := ('0' & a) + ('0' & b);
      s   <= tmp(31 downto 0);
      co  <= tmp(32);
    end if;
  end process;

end architecture rtl;
```

Comment: You forgot the clock :-)

Comment: @Oldfart: you're right, I focused on the arithmetic problem. Updated the answer.

Answer (score 1):

You have to extend op_1, op_2 to 33 bits (Adding a zero at the top as the numbers are unsigned, for signed values you would replicate the top bit). The result (sum) also must be 33 bits.

Do a normal 33+33 bit addition (with all the conversions in VHDL).
Then split off the sum[32] as the carry.

Comment: As this is not complete, I consider this more a comment then an answer

Comment: @JHBonarius I assume with 'complete' I assume you mean I did not show working VHDL code. It does answer the question and as far as I know writing code is customary, not obligatory.

Comment: There's no reference to numeric_std, which replaces the functions in std_logic_unsigned (and is part of the standard). There's no mention of using a clocked statement.

Comment: 1/ Questioner uses a Verilog construct know mostly to more experienced users, thus I placed him there.2/ That makes that I interpret the question as: as there a VHDL short cut like in Verilog? Actual complete answer is thus NO. 3/ User mentions himself that he knows STD_LOGIC_UNSIGNED is nonstandard.

Comment: Thank you, too bad I cannot "tick" two answers. I guess I should select the most complete one.